# difference var and Type. Why doesnt var work here?

Tags: c#, .net

I dont understand why var m does not return Match. I havent checked but it seems to be returning an object.

```
        foreach (var m in Regex.Matches("dummy text", "(mm)"))
            var sz = m.Groups[1]; // error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Groups' and no extension method 'Groups' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("dummy text", "(mm)"))
            var sz = m.Groups[1]; //ok
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MatchCollection` implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<Match>` hence the compiler can only infer the type of the variable as `object` rather than `Match`.

Comment: You win for explaining everything i wanted to know when the least amount of words.

Comment: and i feel this answer is complete.

Comment: Thanks, glad I left my short and sweet answer on!

Answer (score 11):

`Regex.Matches` returns `MatchCollection` that implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<Match>`.

Therefore the default item type is object. When using item type `Match` in the *foreach* you get the expected item type.

Comment: You mean "returns" instead of "implements".

Comment: Thank Stefan, I missed the return type in answer :)

Answer (score 7):

`var` **infers** the type of the variable at *compile time* from the type of the expression it's initialized to. `Matches` returns `MatchCollection` which implements the old school `IEnumerable` and not the generic `IEnumerable<Match>`. The type of the `Current` property returned by the enumerator returned from `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` is `object`. Thus, `var` will infer the type of `m` to be `object` and not `Match`.

When you explicitly specify the type in a `foreach` statement and the return type of the enumerator differs, the compiler will silently insert a cast instruction to make that work. No other compile time check can be performed in that case and it will throw an `InvalidCastException` at run time in case it fails.